# Move animated movieClips using buttons instead of arrow keys

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, animation

I'm trying to develop a game where I want my character to run when I click a button, and continue running if I hold the button. I'm new to ActionScript 3, so I'm a bit lost here.

I've found code that satisfies my requirements; but it uses the arrow keys, as below:

```
function moveRunKei() {
    if (Key.isDown(Key.RIGHT)) {
        dx = 15; //speed
        runKei._xscale = 50;
    } else if (Key.isDown(Key.LEFT)) {
        dx = -15;
        runKei._xscale = -50;
    } else {
        dx = 0;
    }

    runKei._x += dx;

    if (runKei._x < 100) runKei._x = 100; //30
    if (runKei._x > 550) runKei._x = 550;

    if (dx != 0 && runKei._currentframe == 1) {
        runKei.gotoAndPlay("run");
    } else if (dx == 0 && runKei._currentframe != 1) {
        runKei.gotoAndStop("stand");
    }
}

this.onEnterFrame = function(){
    moveRunKei();
}
```

I need to be able to do this using buttons.

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
import flash.events.Event;

var mouseDown:Boolean;
var speed:Number=4;
addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onMouseDown);
addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onMouseUp);
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);


function onMouseDown(event:MouseEvent):void
{
  mouseDown = true;
}

function onMouseUp(event:MouseEvent):void
{
  mouseDown = false;
}

function onEnterFrame(event:Event):void
{
  if (mouseDown)
  {
        runKei.gotoAndPlay("Run");
    runKei.x += speed;

  }

}
```

This code able to make my character move continuously when I hold the button but it didn't animate while it move(the character freeze until I release the button) - I'm not sure how to explain it.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add event listeners for mouse down and mouse up on each of the buttons for movement. Then have booleans that keep track of whether or not the button is down.

It's worth mentioning the code you've linked seems to be actionscript2 so I've changed it to work with as3

```
var leftDown:Boolean = false;
var rightDown:Boolean = true;

leftButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onMouseDown)
rightButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onMouseDown)
leftButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onMouseUp)
rightButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onMouseUp)
leftButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, onMouseUp)
rightButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, onMouseUp)

function onMouseDown(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    //since you can't click on two things at once, this is fine.
    rightDown = (e.target == rightButton);
    leftDown = (e.target == rightButton);
}

function onMouseDown(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    //since you can't click on two things at once, this is fine.
    rightDown = (e.target == rightButton);
    leftDown = (e.target == leftButton);
}

function moveRunKei()
{
    if (rightDown) {
        dx = 15; //speed
        runKei.scaleX = -0.5;
    } else if (leftDown) {
        dx = -15;
        runKei.scaleX = -0.5;
    } else {
        dx = 0;
    }

    runKei.x += dx;

    if (runKei.x < 100) runKei.x = 100; //30
    if (runKei.x > 550) runKei.x = 550;

    if (dx != 0 && runKei.currentFrame == 1)
    {
        runKei.gotoAndPlay("run");
    }
    else if (dx == 0 && runKei.currentFrame != 1)
    {
        runKei.gotoAndStop("stand");
    }
}

    this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);

function onEnterFrame(e:Event):void
{
    moveRunKei();
}
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply. I tried the coding but I got an error saying 1120: Access of undefined property dx. What does it mean?

Comment: you're using a variable called dx in there several times. That is your delta x, that's how fast he should be moving.  That error means that you've not declared it. Just stick "var dx:number" (minus speach marks) at the top, near leftDown and rightDown

Comment: I put the code up and the error disappear. But when I run the SWF file my character immediately run across the stage without me clicking the button.

Comment: Make sure you initiate mouseDown with false. you need to do the addEventListeners on your buttons, not on the parent clip, which is what you're doing at the moment